# Poetry Template

Tags: templates

I have got a poetry template request. I found these very old german literature pieces and wanted to save them:

[image]

I managed to get the same font and insert the pictures but I dont know how to get two columns and these nice lines, the title, and the page number. Also, how to put the footnote in the same column. Therefore I wanted to ask if someone could help me with a template that looks like the above. Other versions of poetry templates are also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I deleted my try as a perfect version can be seen in the answers.

P.S.: I looked at the two column overleaf gallery but I always get stuck if I try to use one. There are just too many things for a Latex amateur like me.

Here the pics:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yV0G.jpg)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: don't use `figure`  here you do not want floats, just use `\begin{center}\includegraphics{...}\end{center}`  replacing `center` by `flushright` or `flushleft` depending on the alignment you need in each case. use `\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}` to get two columns

Comment: Another possibility: Create all of the per-page graphics as a single large image, including the lines. Put it in the background, then use `textpos` to position blocks of text.

Comment: Can you please add the images from your code to your question? (Open image in a viewer, select all, copy, paste. Best write the desired filename before it) Or do you have an online storage for them? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO Or just use images from the `mwe` package.

Comment: Are you aware there's a `verse` environment in LaTeX? For more sophisticated and flexible configuration, there's also a `verse` package (which is what I usually use). Probably this doesn't exhaust the options on CTAN.

Comment: Don't set e.g. `\headheight` directly if using `geometry`. There's no point asking `geometry` to configure your page and then sneaking behind its back while it's not looking. Don't load packages you don't need (are you sure you need all these?).

Comment: Unrelated, but do not use `\mathfrak` to typeset Fraktur. Instead, choose the right font (like you did for the body text). Also note that in Fraktur there are two different kinds of s, a long one (ſ) and a round one (s), and you need to make sure to distinguish between them correctly (you should probably also take care to typeset the most common set of ligatures, ch, ck and tz, properly). You might want to check the [Unifraktur fonts](https://unifraktur.sourceforge.net) that can help you with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? You may want to use Babel, but you probably don't need hyphenation patterns if all your lines are manually broken.

This is a simple use of the `verse` package, which can typeset far more complex verse forms. I don't use `\poemtitle` here because you only want it in the header. Instead, I define a new command `\setpoemtitle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn,letterpaper,twoside]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709874/ addaswyd o gwestiwn calculatormathematical: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709830/
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength \marginswidth
\setlength \marginswidth{25mm}
\newlength \minorshift
\setlength \minorshift {2mm}
\newlength \bottomsup
\setlength \bottomsup {\marginswidth-3mm-\minorshift}
\newlength \topdrop
\setlength \topdrop {\bottomsup-15pt}
\newlength \minortweak
\setlength \minortweak {\marginswidth-\minorshift}
\usepackage[margin=\marginswidth,headheight=15pt,headsep=3mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{verse}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\NewDocumentCommand \insertimage { O {} m }
{%
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \end{center}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_calculatormathematical_poemtitle_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \setpoemtitle { m }
{
  \clearpage
  \tl_set:Nn \l_calculatormathematical_poemtitle_tl { #1 }
}
\setlength \columnseprule {0.4pt}
\renewcommand \headrulewidth {0pt}
\renewcommand \footrulewidth {0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[loh,reh]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[ch]{\frakfamily\fraklines \l_calculatormathematical_poemtitle_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\poemtitlefont{\frakfamily\fraklines}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \put (\minortweak,-\paperheight) {\rule[\bottomsup]{\textwidth+2\minorshift}{0.4pt}}%
  \put (\minortweak,-\topdrop) {\rule{\textwidth+2\minorshift}{0.4pt}}%
  \ifodd\thepage
    \put (\minortweak,-\paperheight) {\rule[\bottomsup]{0.4pt}{\paperheight-\topdrop-\bottomsup}}%
  \else
  \put ({\marginswidth+\textwidth+\minorshift},-\paperheight) {\rule[\bottomsup]{0.4pt}{\paperheight-\topdrop-\bottomsup}}%
  \fi
}
\graphicspath{{archimedes/}}
\begin{document}
\setpoemtitle{Archimedes.}
{\frakfamily\fraklines 
  \begin{verse}  
    In Syrakus war Hiero König\\
    Und Alles war ihm unterthänig.\\
    Der Goldschmied macht ihm eine Krone,\\
    Der König findet sie nicht Ohne.
  \end{verse}  
  \insertimage[scale=0.2]{7atUc}
  \begin{verse}  
    Das ist der Archimes, sein Schwager,\\
    Ist Mathematiker und mager.
  \end{verse}
  \insertimage[scale=0.2]{FMtsc}
  \begin{verse}  
    Der spricht: „Ich glaub', der Juweliero\\
    Hat Dich betrogen, König Hiero!“
  \end{verse} 
  \begin{verse}  
    Der König fordert den Beweis —\\
    Das macht dem Archimedes heiß;\\
    Und als er stark geochset hat.\\
    Nimmt er am Abend sich ein Bad.
  \end{verse}
  \insertimage[scale=0.2]{I4Irp}
  \begin{verse}  
    Bald nach ihm kommt ein dicker Mann,\\
    Der richtet Ueberschwemmung an;
  \end{verse} 
  \insertimage[scale=0.2]{EtpKf}
  \begin{verse}  
    „Heureka!“\footnote{\frakfamily\fraklines  „Hat ihm schon!“} ruft gleich Archimedes — \\
    Und wer nur Griechisch kann, versteht es.
  \end{verse}
  \insertimage[scale=0.2]{kDJ7x}
  \begin{verse}  
    Der Krone Werth, kann jetzt er schätzen\\
    Nach hydrostatischen Gesetzen:\\
    Ein Klumpen reinen Goldes, sieht er,\\
    Verdrängt an Wasser g'rad ein Liter.
  \end{verse} 
  \insertimage[scale=0.2]{qGm91}
  \begin{verse}  
    Die Krone ist genauso schwer,\\
    Verdrängt an Wasser aber mehr;\\
    D'rnm ist sie nicht — wie sie doch sollte —\\
    Gefertiget aus reinem Golde.\\
    Und Hiero läßt den Juwelier\\
    Aufhängen gleich vor seiner Thür'.
  \end{verse}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Archimedes verse in 2 columns, illustrated]

I reduced the margins a bit because they looked far too big once the page was split into two columns. Obviously, this is adjustable, as are my choices of margins, rule thicknesses etc.

Comment: Obviously the transposition of one verse with one image is a deliberate mistake just to see if people are paying attention.

Comment: Very satisfying answer. Little side question: If I wanted to insert a picture that stretches along the two columns, say, below the title, then do I need to change the layout settings for the middle line or does it simply get shorter? Because on further sides I would not want it to be shorter. Is is possible to insert a picture that way?

Comment: @calculatormathematical I suggest asking a followup question. There are various ways to do that but none are exactly straightforward. Changing the line in the centre isn't the problem. It's rather that you need a different layout for that page. At least, that's how I'd do it. I'd put the picture into the header, increase the height of the header and reduce the text height. Or you could use `multicols` rather than `twocolumn`, for example, which would need a completely different approach.